# Dragging down the screen pulling the entire screen down in ios devices

Tags: ios, react-native, scroll

How to get rid of this drag action in ios devices react native? It shows white space. It gives the feel of refreshing the screen.

Comment: If you're using `FlatList` or `ScrollView`, try setting the `bounces={false}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to utilise the 'bounces' prop which belongs to react native's ScrollView.

This is an iOS only prop.

E.g.

```
<ScrollView bounces={false}></ScrollView>

<FlatList bounces={false} />
```

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#bounces-ios